# What does actually character array in java store as an element a char or a unicode value?

Tags: java, arrays, unicode, casting, char

```
char[] rotk = U.toCharArray();

            for (int j = 0; j < rotk.length; j++) {
                rotk[j]+=cipher;
                 if(rotk[j]>122)
                {
                    rotk[j]=(char)(96+(rotk[j]-122));
                }
            }
```

if character is stored inside the char array then in if statement how its getting compared with 122 and if not then why in this statement `rotk[j]=(char)(96+(rotk[j]-122));` we are type casting it into char again?

**Pls help me to understand the scenario of type casting and element that is being getting stored in char array?**

Comment: ```96+(rotk[j]-122``` - Java always converts the type of the expression to the highest level. Here, this expression results in an int, which can store a lot more values than a char. It is similar to the error ```long l = 5; int i = l;```.  Here ```l``` is long which is 64-bit, while i is 32-bit, so cannot fit in it.  So you have to type-cast and say that you understand and accept the consequences. Similarly, int is 4 byte, and char is 2 bytes. So you have to explicitly type-cast

Comment: so in char array is it stored as an integral value or specific character?

Comment: Alternatively you can just do `if(rotk[j]>'z') rotk[j]-=26;` -- the Latin alphabet is well known to contain 26 letters, and compound assignments like `+= -= *=` etc automatically convert (equivalent to cast) back to the LHS type.

Comment: @SatyamMishra as the documentation says: "*`char`, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing **UTF-16 code units***". Do you understand what a "code unit" is? Read about [UTF-16 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)